# How to install Rosetta 2 manually?

Tags: apple-silicon, rosetta-2

Rosetta installation dialog is shown when install application which needs Rosetta to run.

But how can I install Rosetta without such an application?
Rosetta is not available in App Store.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open 'Terminal'
2. `softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license`